# Scala Shapeless - Iterating/reading each item of Generic.Repr or converting it to HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm learning shapeless and referring a tutorial from [here](http://jto.github.io/articles/getting-started-with-shapeless/). Which says,

> Generic is a simple way to convert case class and product types (like
>   tuples) to HList, and vice-versa:

```
import shapeless.Generic

case class UserWithAge(name: String, age: Int)
val gen = Generic[UserWithAge]
val u = UserWithAge("Julien", 30)

val h = gen.to(u)
```

Now if I print `h`, I will get `Julien :: 30 :: HNil`. But, I'm unable to read each element from `h` such as `h.head` , `h.tail` will not work and there aren't any methods available in `h`. Here, `h` is type of `gen.Repr` and I couldn't figure out a way to convert it into `HList` either. So, how can I read each element from `h`?

Comment: The code you provided probably doesn't convey the problem you are having. Because in this code `h.head` and `h.tail` work just fine.

Comment: I was trying in intellij ide instead of repl, which show "cannot resolve symbol head" if I do h.head. However, It complied fine. May be its the problem with ide. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: Oh yes, then it's probably just the IDE having problems with implicits and macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case the type of `gen.to(u)` is `gen.Repr`, which if you look at the type of `gen` actually expends to `String ::  Int :: HNil`, so it's already a `HList`!

```
scala> import shapeless.Generic
import shapeless.Generic

scala> case class UserWithAge(name: String, age: Int)
defined class UserWithAge

scala> val gen = Generic[UserWithAge]
gen: shapeless.Generic[UserWithAge]{type Repr = shapeless.::[String,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.HNil]]} = anon$macro$3$1@4ff329b8

scala> val u = UserWithAge("Julien", 30)
u: UserWithAge = UserWithAge(Julien,30)

scala> val h = gen.to(u)
h: gen.Repr = Julien :: 30 :: HNil

scala> h.head
res0: String = Julien

scala> h.tail
res1: shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.HNil] = 30 :: HNil
```

In the general case, the `Repr` type of a `Generic` will be either a `HList` or a `Coproduct`. For examples of how to generically program over these, see [shapeless-type-class-derivation-2015-demo](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless-type-class-derivation-2015-demo).